# MonacaならばAndroidで動画を自動再生させる事が出来るか

Tags: monaca, 動画, audio-streaming

HTML5およびJavaScriptによるWebsiteを持っています。
Androidで動作する、ビデオやオーディオを使ったアプリを作りたいです。

AndroidのChromeではvideoタグやaudioタグでオートプレイを（autoplay属性などで）行うことが出来ません。従量課金の懸念による制限のため、オートプレイが不可能な現状です。

Monacaでは可能なようですので、アプリ化しても動作可能であれば登録したいのです。
monacaの中のプライベートアプリとしては、サーバーへリンクを飛ばし、それをオート再生することができます。

- AndroidのChromeではできないオートプレイを実行する手段はありますか？
- ストレージに配置するHTMLファイルに、ダウンロードを伴うサーバーへのリンクをはることは可能ですか？
- アイコンの作成は可能ですか？
- 登録に際し、＄25以外に何か必要ですか。
- xmlファイルの編集は必要ですか？

来月本を買って学ぶつもりですが、事前に知りたいのです。なにとぞよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: この方が分かり易いと思うので、編集しました。このサイトは他人でも編集出来る仕組みになっていますので、びっくりしないで下さい。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 動画等の自動再生に関して

Cordova・Monacaではvideo要素等の自動再生が可能です。
video要素にautoplay属性を付けておけば、アプリケーションの起動時に自動で再生が始まります。

ただしアプリケーションの切り替えなどで再生が止まります。
再びアクティブになった時に再生を再開したいのなら、pauseやresumeなどのイベントを補足し適切に処理する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。monacaの導入を考えていきます。